# php add 15 minutes time interval to current time loop it till midnight

Tags: php

I need to add 15 minutes to the current time till the day's midnight.which should shows in the below format

```
11:15am
11:30am
11:45am
```

And it 'ld not be,

```
11:25am
11:40am
11:55am
```

My code is

```
$start =strtotime(date("d-m-Y h:i:s"));//strtotime('6:00am');
//echo $start;
//$end =strtotime('midnight');
$end = strtotime('12:00');//
$range = array();
while ($start <= $end)
{
echo date('h:ia',$start )."</br>";
$start = strtotime('+15 minutes',$start);
}
```

The above code results ,

```
11:28am
11:43am
11:58am
```

**Question 1:**

How to give end time as today midnight?

When I try `strtotime('midnight')`, it returns empty data.

**Question 2:**

How to display rounded time to nearest quarter?

Comment: do you want round or floor, that's different

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more.. Too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `24:00` or `'tomorrow midnight'` to get the next midnight. Your code use `12:00` which is "this noon".

```
$min = round(date("i") / 15) * 15;
$start = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:$min:00"));
$end = strtotime('24:00');
$range = array();
while ($start <= $end)
{
    echo date('h:ia',$start )."</br>";
    $start = strtotime('+15 minutes',$start);
}
```

Will outputs:

```
08:15am
08:30am
...
11:30pm
11:45pm
12:00am
```

If you don't want to include "12:00am", you could change `<=` to `<`:

```
while ($start < $end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your code must be started exactly `11:00` to get `after 15 mins` to be `11:15`.

You can create start time as `11:00:00` to properly set time ([demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71259f75174d53e06564d4da48d4f88e1ee8c0c8)):

```
$start =strtotime(date("h:00"));
$end = strtotime('12:00');
$range = array();

while ($start <= $end)
{
    $range[] = date('h:ia',$start );
    $start = strtotime('+15 minutes',$start);
}

var_dump($range);
```