# End the for loop if a time is greater that 12am

Tags: php, date

My date format is 24hours. i want to display timing in the select dropdown from start time to end time based on interval timing. I want to end the loop, if time is reach or greater than 12am.

In my case, the start time is 15:00 and the interval is 50 minutes. Then the end time becomes 23:30, because its the last time we can get with 50 minute interval before reaching midnight.

```
<?php 
       $cooking_time=50;
       $interval=50;
?>
<select name="preorder_time">
            <?php                                   
                for($i=0;$i<145;$i++){                
                    $curtime=date('H:i',strtotime("+$interval minutes",$startime));
                    if($curtime>=date('H:i',$endtime))
                    break;
                    $interval=$interval+$cooking_time;
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo strtotime($curtime); ?>">Today <?php echo $curtime; ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
</select>
```

The output is

```
<select name="preorder_time">
                <option value="1564411800">Today 15:50</option>
                <option value="1564414800">Today 16:40</option>
                <option value="1564417800">Today 17:30</option>
                <option value="1564420800">Today 18:20</option>
                <option value="1564423800">Today 19:10</option>
                <option value="1564426800">Today 20:00</option>
                <option value="1564429800">Today 20:50</option>
                <option value="1564432800">Today 21:40</option>
                <option value="1564435800">Today 22:30</option>
                <option value="1564438800">Today 23:20</option>
       <!-- But I want to End the for loop here, before midnight -->
                <option value="1564355400">Today 00:10</option>
                <option value="1564358400">Today 01:00</option>
                <option value="1564361400">Today 01:50</option>
                <option value="1564364400">Today 02:40</option>
                <option value="1564367400">Today 03:30</option>
                <option value="1564370400">Today 04:20</option>
                <option value="1564373400">Today 05:10</option>
                <option value="1564376400">Today 06:00</option>
                <option value="1564379400">Today 06:50</option>
                <option value="1564382400">Today 07:40</option>
                <option value="1564385400">Today 08:30</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49870809/2943403  <-- but not marking this one as a duplicate because Qirel's answer is superior to the `strtotime()` techniques there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateTime objects -- create an object with the start-time (which will be today), and one for midnight tomorrow (which is simply the timestring "tomorrow"). Declare a loop where you continue to loop until the `$date` object (which will be modified inside the loop) is greater or equal to the `$tomorrow` object. Inside the loop, add `$interval` minutes for each iteration.

```php
<?php 
$cooking_time = 50;
$interval = 50;

$start_time = "15:00";
$end_time = "22:00";

$date = new DateTime($start_time);
$end = new DateTime($end_time);
if ($date > $end) {
    $end->modify("+1 day");
}
?>
<select name="preorder_time">                           
    <?php
    while ($date < $end) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $date->getTimestamp(); ?>"><?php echo $date->format("H:i"); ?></option>
        <?php 
        $date->modify("+$interval minute");
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/N09Bq

Comment: He wants use timestamp as option value.
<option value="<?php echo $date->getTimestamp(); ?>"><?php echo $format; ?></option>

Comment: https://3v4l.org/GDgXD  I just read some debate in the comments at the bottom of that docs page.  Perhaps go with `U`.

Comment: Referring to the concern of timezones? Or which comment did you refer to?

Comment: Yeah, the timezone thing.  p.s. I wonder if there is any risk of ambiguity in the `$start_time` variable.  Might the DateTime object instantiation ever accidentally get tripped up (because it is a pure time value) and assume the wrong day, or will it always find "today"?

Comment: Thanks for your response. my start time and end time is dynamic. what if my end time is 22:00. the loop should be end before 22.00.

Comment: See the revised answer.